# How can I generalize this model_post_init in Pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a human-editable YAML configuration where I'd like to allow fields that are either strings or lists:

```yaml
examples:
  foo: red
  bar: red, green
  qaz: 
    - red
    - green
    - blue
```

This is intended to be deserialized as

```py
{
  "examples": {
    "foo": ["red"],
    "bar": ["red", "green"],
    "qaz": ["red", "green", "blue"]
  }
}
```

I've implemented a function that takes a `list[str] | str` and performs this transformation and I'm using it like this:

```py
class SomeMode(BaseModel):
    foo: str | list[str]
    bar: str | list[str]

    def model_post_init(self, __context):
        self.foo = process_composite_list(self.foo, separator=",")
        self.bar = process_composite_list(self.bar, separator=",")
        return super().model_post_init(__context)
```

This works very well, but I'm finding that I want to introduce the same behavior in various other models. Humans who edit this YAML will expect this mechanism everywhere. Is there a way to annotate fields in such a way that this function is called automatically when data is being deserialized (in any model, without having to one-by-one add a model_post_init)? (serialization is not a concern, only deserialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`PlainValidator`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_validators/#pydantic.functional_validators.PlainValidator):

```py
import typing
import pydantic

MyList = typing.Annotated[
    str | list[str],
    pydantic.PlainValidator(lambda x: process_composite_list(x, separator=',')),
    # Or
    # pydantic.PlainValidator(functools.partial(process_composite_list, separator=','))
]

class SomeMode(pydantic.BaseModel):
    foo: MyList
    bar: MyList
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a flexible record for the `str | list[str]` type.

```
class SomeMode(BaseModel):
  foo: flexible_field
  bar: flexible_field

  def model_post_init(self, __context):
    return super().model_post_init(__context)
```

Where your flexible_field is defined as

```
import pydantic

flexible_field = Field (
  type_=str | list[str],
  default=[],  # or any other default value of a field, if the value is not provided during deserialisation
  alias="flexibel field",
  deserializer=FlexibleFieldDeserialiser.deserialise
)
```

The deserialiser class then could look like this:

```
import typing
import pydantic

class FlexibleFieldDeserialiser(BaseModel):
  data: Union[str, list[str]]

  @staticmethod
  def deserialise(value: str):
    if "," in value:
      return value.split(",")
    else:
      return [value]
```

Note: I have not tested this as I consider it purely conceptual at this stage.